# quartz scheduler log4j duplicate messages

Tags: log4j

I use log4j for logging. Now i add quartz scheduler to schedule some job.
But every log message would got print twice, once is by quartz worker thread.
Could someone please help me to stop one of these two dups?
Thank you very much.
I didn't configure any log thing for quartz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excerpt of log4j configuration file would be helpful...

A wild guess is there is a separate appender for Quartz defined and this appender is additive (by default). Either (1) remove the extra appender, and leave only root logger's, or (2) make the responsible logger non-additive, or (3) redirect the appender to write somewhere (i.e. another file).